# Sign out website like TFS web portal did

Tags: tfs, teamcity, tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem

I am attempting to write a website that connects to TFS and retrieves work item information

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080/tfs", cred);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

When I logged in by this way, I would like to sign out like web portal of TFS. Could you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to teamcity.

Comment: Can you expand further? I'm also not sure exactly what you're getting at.  Those credentials are only valid for the lifetime of that variable, it should be getting recreated each web request. Signout isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks you so much Betty, I want integrate sign in and sign out function into my website. I think "Sign in" function, I will base on code above but I don't know for "sign out" function.

Comment: And when user logged into site, I can show the text like "Hello user 1"

Answer (score 2):

You probably should be using windows auth with kerberos delegation instead.

That means the user doesn't need to enter their username/password as they're already authenticated by logging into the domain and there is no real need for a sign out function.

See [Passthrough (impersonation) authentication with ASP.NET and TFS api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013081/passthrough-impersonation-authentication-with-asp-net-and-tfs-api) for more details

Answer (score 0):

you should use the TFS APi's . to get work item fields u have to select wistore.
you can check the "shai raiton" artical on that.
google it as shai raiton tfs.
i remembered that he make a tool from which he can get the all work item (delete them in bulk).
search for it u can definatly finds answer!
vote up if it helps!

Comment: So great Mak But I can't find it with this keyword "shai raiton" or any related keyword was the same.

Comment: I found the blog out "Shai Raiten's Blog". I think, you want to say about it

Comment: yes im saying that! sorry i spelled it wrong......... i have checked his blog moths ago.thatz why i cant remember it correct map!